# Nest n-times a multi-variable function with only one of the variables being updated with previous function value

Tags: function-construction, programming, symbolic

I have a function y1 of three variables, x, y, and z. (y1 also depends upon f1 defined previously). I would like to Nest or interate, such that on the nth iteration, the y1's 3rd variable, z, will be replaced by the (n-1) value of y1. I want to be able calculate nth result for y1 as a function of x and y (z having been replaced previous (n-1) y1 value). I suspect I must use Nest? (novice user).

```
f1[x_, y_] := If[x > y, Sqrt[x^2 - y^2], 10^-5]
y1[x_, y_, z_] := ((
  z + (1 + z) (x/f1[x, y] Sin[f1[x, y]])^2)/(Cos[
      f1[x, y]] + (y/f1[x, y]) Sin[f1[x, y]])^2)
```

For instance after the nth step of a loop (if it were in Fortran), I'd like to obtain the function, y_sub n[x,y,z]=y[x,y,(y_sub (n-1))]. I need to be able to evaluate the this result for arbitrary x and y values.

Comment: ```Clear["Global`*"]``` and to demonstrate using a yet undefined function: `NestList[g1[x, y, #] &, 1, 3]` gives `{1, g1[x, y, 1], g1[x, y, g1[x, y, 1]], 
 g1[x, y, g1[x, y, g1[x, y, 1]]]}` which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much Syed - that indeed worked. Don't know what # and & mean though.

Comment: You can put your cursor at the symbol and press F1 for help. `#` stands for an empty slot that receives an argument and `&` represents the end of the pure function definition. On the initial pass, the slot takes the value `1` and gives a result. This result is used in the same slot on the second `Nest`ing pass and so on.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.